# Delete multiple element from PHP with non strict criterias

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is created from `readdir` function, let's say like this one:

`$array = array("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","~file1.txt","~file3.txt")`

I don't know exact name of the files which have `~` character. I want to exclude all values which have `~` so the array should be:

`$array = array("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt")`

Can you tell me, how can I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($var){
    return strpos($var, '~') === false;
});

print_r($array);
```

Or for < PHP 5.3:

```
function filter($var){
    return strpos($var, '~') === false;
}

$array = array_filter($array, 'filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also go with a `foreach`

```
$res = array();
foreach($array as $v){
    if ($v[0] != '~'){
        $res[] = $v;
    }
}
```

but i'd stick with array_filter

Answer (score 0):

```
for($count=0; $count<=count($array); $count++)
{
    //echo $array[$count];
    if(strpos($array[$count],'~')!==false)
        unset($array[$count]);      
}
$array=array_values($array);
```